# JQuery - Country code with fully customization

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

```
<div class="box">
  <select class="ignore">
    <option value="1">Some option</option>
    <option value="2">Another option</option>
    <option value="3" disabled>A disabled option</option>
    <option value="4">Potato</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I'm trying to create a country phone code drop-down with customization.

Here I'm trying to use `jquery-nice-select` plugin. What I want to know is, is it possible to create country phone code selector using `jquery-nice-select` plugin? I didn't get a way for that, so can you guys can help me? I have attached my HTML code above.

https://hernansartorio.com/jquery-nice-select/

Comment: Have you tried to put the countries code as options in your html code?

Comment: So the question is, `is it possible to create country phone code selector?` I'd say yes, but the question is way too broad. We don't exactly know what you are trying to achieve. It's like asking, "is it possible to make a website?", well yes it is :)